# Javascript to access usb HID (usb game controller)

Tags: javascript, usb, hid

Im looking to use Javascript to read events from a usb device other than a keyboard or mouse. Specifically, I want to use a usb gaming controller to read events. If this isnt possible with Javascript, is there anything else thats on the browser and client side that would allow me to do this? Im not above having the user accept permission for something, install a plugin, or limit them to a particular browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you used flash and maybe you could have flash detect controller strokes but I don't think any browser script would allow that. That would awesome tho!

Comment: Would this be possible in some context of a browser plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Gamepad API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/GamepadAPI) that exists for this very reason.

Comment: Perfect. Thats exactly what im looking for.